# Google Translate Voices download using C#

Tags: c#, freetts

as the title said i was following this code posted on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390702/download-from-google-translate) to download tts on my application folder and play it back so that it gave my application the ability to talk Arabic to Arab users, since i cant find an engine which work offline with Arabic languish i used this method and it was working as expected,but for some reason i don't know , it stopped working it says the `remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable`.
i tested it directly on the browser and it worked but not working on my application any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could've used something like "Tamper Data" to follow your link and check what the result is.

I've tried opening the link a few times to check an Idea. This is my Tamper-Screen after a few requests:

[image]

As you can see the status is `503` which is your `Server Unavailable`.
If continuing following the link you will see the result on the website:

[image]

You get prompted to go through the captcha-code. Thats your problem. After trying and trying while coding, you get blocked by google.

**In general:**
Google is one of the worst websites according building own api's due to their strong blocking. So fetching any data by html-requests just sucks. If even google, then real provided api's from google.

I already tried building own stuff on the base of their work. Failes all time because of the captchas.

*Sorry for the bad news...*

Comment: isn't there any other site that offer the same service ?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387212/how-to-convert-text-string-to-speech-sound. Consider marking as solved as this question is done.

Comment: it doesnt support arabic ?

Comment: Dont know. If this as problem for you, go and ask another question to help with text-to-speech. Im not familiar with it, sorry.

Comment: And keep http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png in mind. Untagged dead questions are ugly.